# Micropython проблема с UART

Tags: hex, uart, micropython

По определенным причинам было принято решение перейти с ардуиновского С на микропитон и уперся в проблему, а именно:
строка с hex которые работают в С и устройство на них отвечает:

`byte Data1[] = {0x5A, 0xA5, 0x01, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x01, 0x10, 0x1E, 0x70, 0xFF};`

но как бы я не пробовал отправлять ее через микропитона все четно. В качестве МК пробовал разный устройства, ESP32, ESP8266, RP.

`bytes([0x5A, 0xA5, 0x01, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x01, 0x10, 0x1E, 0x70, 0xFF])`  не работает
`b'\x5A\xA5\x01\x3D\x22\x01\x10\x1E\x70\xFF'` не работает (в разных вариациях)

Часть кода на С:

```
void setup() {
  load();
  Serial.begin(115200,SERIAL_8N1);
  Serial.setTimeout(100);

}

byte Data1[] = {0x5A, 0xA5, 0x01, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x01, 0x10, 0x1E, 0x70, 0xFF};
Serial.write(Data1, sizeof(Data1));
delay(10);
while (Serial.available() > 0) {            
    strData += String(Serial.read(), HEX);       
    delay(10);                              
  }
```

Часть кода на микропитоне:

```
send_hex = b"5AA5013D2201101E70FF"
uart = UART(0, 115200, timeout = 100, tx=Pin(12), rx=Pin(13),invert=0)  
uart.write(send_hex)
utime.sleep(0.2)
recv=bytes()
while uart.any()>0:
    utime.sleep(0.2)
    recv+=uart.read(1)
print (recv)
```

С компа, через TTL отвечает на `bytes.fromhex("5A A5 01 3D 22 01 10 1E 70 FF")` но то же самое с микро не работает.

На выходе этого кода:

```
uart = UART(0, 115200, timeout = 5, tx=Pin(12), rx=Pin(13),invert=0)                        
uart.init(115200, bits=8, parity=None, stop=1) 


test = b'\x5A\xA5\x01\x3D\x22\x01\x10\x1E\x70\xFF'


print(test)
print("Machine: \t" + uos.uname()[4]) # для информации о плате
print("MicroPython: \t" + uos.uname()[3]) # для информации о версии питона
print(f"TYPE - {type(test)}")


uart.write(test)
utime.sleep(0.2)
recv=bytes()
while uart.any()>0:
    utime.sleep(0.2)
    recv+=uart.read(1)
print (recv)
```

получается вот это:

```
b'Z\xa5\x01="\x01\x10\x1ep\xff'
Machine:    Raspberry Pi Pico with RP2040
MicroPython:    v1.20.0 on 2023-04-26 (GNU 12.1.0 MinSizeRel)
TYPE - <class 'bytes'>
b'\x00'
```

Направьте в правильное русло.

Заранее огромно спасибо.

Comment: Скорость UART правильная настроена?

Comment: Проверил в первую очередь. скорость верная.

Comment: Тогда нужно смотреть как вы отправляете данные, т.е. код нужен

Comment: В сам вопрос добавьте код как было на arduino и как делаете через micropython

Comment: Поправил. Добавил части кода. В питоне привел один из множества вариантов типа отправляемых данных.

Comment: `b"5AA5013D2201101E70FF"` - вот так точно не будет работать

Comment: Из очевидных отличий - на python в цикле нет паузы. Не знаю, влияет ли это на что-то, но я бы добавил, чтобы точно код был идентичным.

Comment: Это уже отчаяние)))) Я пробовал даже дурные варианты)))

Comment: Задержка не чего не меняет, но я поправил.

Comment: Вы можете установить перехватчик типа AccessPort и сравнить параметры открытия порта и реально пересылаемые данные?

Comment: Забыл указать что с компа, через TTL отвечает на `bytes.fromhex(send_hex)`.

Comment: @ДмитрийЦветков с `bytes.fromhex(send_hex)` не будет работать исходный сишный вариант. Исходно вы не hex передаете, а байты. В текущем micropython варианте - наоборот, hex, а не байты

Comment: bytes.fromhex("5A A5 01 3D 22 01 10 1E 70 FF")

Comment: "но то же самое с микро не работает." - есть разные оттенки серого, т.е. "не работает". В этом случае это не работает, потому что на micropython у bytes нет метода fromhex. Указывайте как конкретно "не работает".

Comment: Прошу прощения, метод есть. Но устройство на которое отправляю не понимает. На выходе получается `b'Z\xa5\x01="\x01\x10\x1ep\xff'`

Comment: В коде на micropython оставьте `bytes([0x5A, 0xA5, 0x01, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x01, 0x10, 0x1E, 0x70, 0xFF])` или `b'\x5A\xA5\x01\x3D\x22\x01\x10\x1E\x70\xFF'`, и больше не меняйте, проблема не в этом.

Comment: @ДмитрийЦветков `b'Z\xa5\x01="\x01\x10\x1ep\xff'` == `b'\x5A\xA5\x01\x3D\x22\x01\x10\x1E\x70\xFF'`, проблема не в этом (но не равно `b"5AA5013D2201101E70FF"`)

Comment: Еще, по документации не понятно, обязателен ли вызов метода init, попробуйте добавить `uart.init(115200)` после создания объекта.

Comment: @insolor добавлял, но он больше нужен для инициализации в случае нескольких UART на МК, или смены скорости для взаимодействия с разными устройствами.

Comment: С id, tx, rx могут быть какие-нибудь проблемы. На "малых" платах (esp) uart может не на любых пинах работать, про rpi не знаю. Сверьтесь с доками на всякий случай.

Comment: tx=Pin(12), rx=Pin(13) это на какой плате? на есп не запустится

Comment: @eri это на данный момент RP2040

Comment: @insolor данные пины работают на С. Я их не менял физически.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала проверить что данные в принципе отправляются, например пробуйте отправлять на комп вместо устройства

Comment: @insolor Проверял компом и осцилографом. Данные летят. Так же пробовал кольцевать RX и TX все возвращается

Comment: Ок, тогда возможно какие-то различия в конфигурации. Как вариант, тем же осцилографом записать оба варианта сигнала и сравнить.

Comment: @insolor Сравнивал. Они разные. в С 10 байт с последним а в питоне 9.

Comment: Так что перехватчик показывает?

Comment: @MBo еще не проверял, рядом нет компа на винде. А на мак подобной софтины не нашел

Comment: уарт переходник подцепи

Comment: Ради эксперимента добавьте uart.flush() после write

Comment: @insolor Добавил. А воз и ныне там. Эффекта 0

Comment: @eri поподробнее если можно

Comment: usb-uart подцепи и посмотри что прилетает при write